# Can't figure out how to get the src (full path) of a specific img with the class name cboxPhoto

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm new to PHP and JavaScript/jQuery.

I'm looking to create a variable of the src of an image that's showing in a lightbox (colorbox) type "window" so that I can pass that variable to other variables in order to be able to share the photo via social media. Here's the code I have now that's not working:

```
var imgSrc   = $('.cboxPhoto').attr('src');
var twitter  = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='+imgSrc+'&text=Check out JG Pet Photography&hashtags=dogs,photos'>&#xf099;</a>";
var facebook = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+imgSrc+'>&#xf230;</a>";
var google   = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://plus.google.com/share?url='+imgSrc+'>&#xf0d5;</a>";

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery('#cboxContent').append(
    '<div id="cboxSocial" class="icon-soc">' + imgSrc + twitter + facebook + google + shop + '</div><div class="clear"></div>'); 
});
```

The class cboxPhoto only shows up when the lightbox is activated. Not sure if that matters. You can see it working/not working at www.jeffreygelt.photography. Just scroll down and click on one of the photos.

Comment: You need to write the `attr()` after click event. Writing it on page load will give you `undefined` as the class element is generated later.

Comment: use prop instead of attr as attr gives static value where prop gives the dynamic value. Also put that in document.ready

Answer (score 1):

There are a few isues here:

1. the issue is the timing of your `$('.cboxPhoto').attr('src');` call... it's running before the document is ready for that selector to find the node.
2. There's another issue: you're mis-using your quotes when creating `twitter`,`google`, etc.

Move everything into your onReady function and then change the single quotes into double-quotes ten including the variable and it should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var imgSrc   = $('.cboxPhoto').attr('src');
        var twitter  = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url="+imgSrc+"&text=Check out JG Pet Photography&hashtags=dogs,photos'>&#xf099;</a>";
        var facebook = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+imgSrc+">&#xf230;</a>";
        var google   = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://plus.google.com/share?url="+imgSrc+">&#xf0d5;</a>";
        jQuery('#cboxContent').append(
        '<div id="cboxSocial" class="icon-soc">' + imgSrc + twitter + facebook + google + shop + '</div><div class="clear"></div>'); 
    });
```

If you're trying to make this happen when `$('.cboxPhoto').attr('src');` is clicked then you need to assign the onclick-handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $('.cboxPhoto').click(function(){
        var imgSrc   = $(this).attr('src');
        var twitter  = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url="+imgSrc+"&text=Check out JG Pet Photography&hashtags=dogs,photos'>&#xf099;</a>";
        var facebook = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+imgSrc+">&#xf230;</a>";
        var google   = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://plus.google.com/share?url="+imgSrc+">&#xf0d5;</a>";
        jQuery('#cboxContent').append(
        '<div id="cboxSocial" class="icon-soc">' + imgSrc + twitter + facebook + google + shop + '</div><div class="clear"></div>'); 
      });
    });
```

Lastly, if the image in question is being dynamically inserted into the DOM after the page loads, you might want to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document.body).on('click', '.cboxPhoto' ,function(){
    var imgSrc   = $(this).attr('src');
            var twitter  = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url="+imgSrc+"&text=Check out JG Pet Photography&hashtags=dogs,photos'>&#xf099;</a>";
            var facebook = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+imgSrc+">&#xf230;</a>";
            var google   = "<a rel='nofollow' href='https://plus.google.com/share?url="+imgSrc+">&#xf0d5;</a>";
            jQuery('#cboxContent').append(
            '<div id="cboxSocial" class="icon-soc">' + imgSrc + twitter + facebook + google + shop + '</div><div class="clear"></div>'); 

   });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but its still not working. I'm still getting "undefined." @vinayakj, I also tried your advice but it didn't work either.

Comment: Is there something other than document.ready, like an onclick kind of thing? Since the image with class cboxPhoto doesn't exist until the lightbox is opened.

Comment: OK, I just updated the answer (there are several changes)... but if the image doesn't exist when the page loads then it won't work either. Do you have a link to your site/page where this is an issue?

Comment: Thanks for the effort but that's not working either. I tried replacing .cboxPhoto with the element you actually click on to start the lightbox but that didn't work either. I guess I'll try contacting the dev of Colorbox and see what he/she can do for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds good... one more thing to try... see the last chunk of code.. this will attach events to dynamically inserted nodes. If you know the parent node that the image is going to be added to you should use `$([selector for parent node]).on('click', '.cboxPhoto' ,function(){...` but this should work

Comment: Thanks @Ben D and everyone else who tried to help but I finally figured it out. It all had to do with the specific code for the ColorBox. The magic code was: jQuery(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){